# ASA 5520, I cannot communicate to the DMZ

Tags: security

Well im having some serious issue here.

My internal PCs cannot communicate to the DMZ to access the www plus the mail server-
Im a bit new to the game and therefore im n not tchat good at all..   please help

bellow is my ASA sh run

```
ASA Version 7.0(8)
!
hostname ASA2
domain-name parlamento.ao
enable password 8Ry2YjIyt7RRXU24 encrypted
passwd mTKIgScrUQsYFO0h encrypted
names
dns-guard
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 description "Link-To-GW-Router"
 nameif outside
 security-level 0
 ip address 41.223.156.109 255.255.255.248
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 description Link To Local Lan
 nameif inside
 security-level 100
 ip address 10.1.4.1 255.255.252.0
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
 description "Link-To-DMZ"
 nameif dmz
 security-level 50
 ip address 172.16.16.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/3
 shutdown
 no nameif
 no security-level
 no ip address
!
interface Management0/0
 shutdown
 no nameif
 no security-level
 no ip address
!
ftp mode passive
access-list INSIDE extended permit ip 10.1.4.0 255.255.252.0 any
access-list OUT-TO-DMZ extended permit tcp any host 41.223.156.107 eq smtp
access-list OUT-TO-DMZ extended permit tcp any host 41.223.156.106 eq www
access-list OUT-TO-DMZ extended permit icmp any any log
access-list OUT-TO-DMZ extended deny ip any any
access-list inside extended permit tcp any any eq pop3
access-list inside extended permit tcp any any eq smtp
access-list inside extended permit tcp any any eq ssh
access-list inside extended permit tcp any any eq telnet
access-list inside extended permit tcp any any eq https
access-list inside extended permit udp any any eq domain
access-list inside extended permit tcp any any eq domain
access-list inside extended permit tcp any any eq www
access-list inside extended permit ip any any
access-list inside extended permit icmp any any
access-list dmz extended permit ip any any
access-list dmz extended permit icmp any any
access-list DMZ_IN extended permit icmp any any echo
access-list 101 extended permit icmp any any echo-reply
access-list 101 extended permit icmp any any source-quench
access-list 101 extended permit icmp any any unreachable
access-list 101 extended permit icmp any any time-exceeded
access-list cap extended permit ip 172.16.16.0 255.255.255.0 10.1.4.0 255.255.25
2.0
access-list cap extended permit ip 10.1.4.0 255.255.252.0 172.16.16.0 255.255.25
5.0
pager lines 24
mtu outside 1500
mtu inside 1500
mtu dmz 1500
no failover
no asdm history enable
arp timeout 14400
global (outside) 1 interface
nat (inside) 1 10.1.4.0 255.255.252.0
static (dmz,outside) tcp 41.223.156.106 www 172.16.16.80 www netmask 255.255.255
.255
static (dmz,outside) tcp 41.223.156.107 smtp 172.16.16.25 smtp netmask 255.255.2
55.255
static (inside,dmz) 10.1.0.0 10.1.16.0 netmask 255.255.252.0
access-group OUT-TO-DMZ in interface outside
access-group inside in interface inside
access-group dmz in interface dmz
route outside 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 41.223.156.108 1
timeout xlate 3:00:00
timeout conn 1:00:00 half-closed 0:10:00 udp 0:02:00 icmp 0:00:02
timeout sunrpc 0:10:00 h323 0:05:00 h225 1:00:00 mgcp 0:05:00
timeout mgcp-pat 0:05:00 sip 0:30:00 sip_media 0:02:00
timeout uauth 0:05:00 absolute
no snmp-server location
no snmp-server contact
snmp-server enable traps snmp authentication linkup linkdown coldstart
crypto ipsec security-association lifetime seconds 28800
crypto ipsec security-association lifetime kilobytes 4608000
telnet timeout 5
ssh timeout 5
console timeout 0
!
class-map inspection_default
 match default-inspection-traffic
!
!
policy-map global_policy
 class inspection_default
  inspect dns maximum-length 512
  inspect ftp
  inspect h323 h225
  inspect h323 ras
  inspect netbios
  inspect rsh
  inspect rtsp
  inspect skinny
  inspect esmtp
  inspect sqlnet
  inspect sunrpc
  inspect tftp
  inspect sip
  inspect xdmcp
  inspect icmp
!
service-policy global_policy global
Cryptochecksum:30d296dea4f5ffc1dd4560e075d47076
: end
```

Jorge Decimo

Comment: are you trying to access the www and smtp servers via their public address (41.x) or their internal address (172.x)?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have this line?

`static (inside,dmz) 10.1.0.0 10.1.16.0 netmask 255.255.252.0`

It doesn't seem to make sense in your configuration, try removing it.

Also by default, interfaces with higher levels, can access the lower levels, and since the ASA is stateful the traffic will be allowed to return.  So you can remove `access-group dmz in interface dmz`  line as well.

Unless you want to nat you should You should also tell the asa to not NAT the traffic between the DMZ and the inside.

```
 access-list dmz_nat permit ip 172.16.16.1 255.255.255.0 10.1.4.1 255.255.252.0
 nat(dmz) 0 access-list dmz_nat
```

Comment: I'm trying to access them by their internal ip address such as 172.16.16.25 smtp and 172.16.16.80 www but nothing happen